# Ionic 6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have this error when wanting to communicate with API firebase:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
The data comes from the firebase realtime database, however it shows the logs only on the network. Following are the code segments that i have used and i am completely new the ionic development, so kindly point if i made any blunders.

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Offline Mode
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
 
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="loadData(true, $event)">
    <ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
 
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users" tappable (click)="updateUser(user.id)">
      <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
        <img [src]="user.avatar">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <ion-label>
        <h3>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
 
  users:any[]=[];
 
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private plt: Platform) { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadData(true);
    });
  }
 
  loadData(refresh = false, refresher?) {
    this.apiService.getUsers(refresh).subscribe(res => {
      this.users = Object.values(res);
      if (refresher) {
        refresher.target.complete();
      }
    });
  }
 
  updateUser(id) {
    this.apiService.updateUser(id, {name: 'Victor', job: 'CEO'}).subscribe();
  }
  
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { OfflineManagerService } from './offline-manager.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NetworkService, ConnectionStatus } from './network.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

const API_STORAGE_KEY = 'specialkey';
const API_URL = 'https://food-ea070-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private networkService: NetworkService, private storage: Storage, private offlineManager: OfflineManagerService) { }
 
  getUsers(forceRefresh: boolean = false): Observable<any[]> {
    if (this.networkService.getCurrentNetworkStatus() == ConnectionStatus.Offline || !forceRefresh) {
      // Return the cached data from Storage
      return from(this.getLocalData('users'));
    } else {

      // Return real API data and store it locally
      return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/users.json`).pipe(
        map(res => res['data']),
        tap(res => {
          this.setLocalData('users', res);
        })
      )
    }
  }
 
  updateUser(_user, data): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${API_URL}/users.json`;
    if (this.networkService.getCurrentNetworkStatus() == ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
      return from(this.offlineManager.storeRequest(url, 'PUT', data));
    } else {
      return this.http.put(url, data).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          this.offlineManager.storeRequest(url, 'PUT', data);
          throw new Error(err);
        })
      );
    }
  }
 
  // Save result of API requests
  private setLocalData(key, data) {
    this.storage.set(`${API_STORAGE_KEY}-${key}`, data);
  }
 
  // Get cached API result
  private getLocalData(key) {
    return this.storage.get(`${API_STORAGE_KEY}-${key}`);
  }
  
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywcuj.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzug4.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veCya.jpg)

Comment: `Object.values()` would return an array of all the values from the object. And yet in the template you try to access properties like `avatar`, `first_name` and `last_name`. Check again if the `Object.values()` is required. Note: This is most probably not related to the issue shown in the screenshot.

Comment: you do not catch any error on your http.get request but pipe it directly into the map, not knowing whether you succeeded or not, that is why the error just propagates to the top. If you catch it here and print it to console you would see it.
But i would suggest not to use the http client api with firebase but to use the proper firebase clients. Together with angular / ionic there is also AngularFire which i can recommend. Check out the docs on both firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start and AngularFire https://github.com/angular/angularfire.